# Filtering a field with multiple values pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Quite a basic question, apologies if its been asked before but couldnt find the answer.

Trying to filter a dataset based on gender so that I can see the girl-boy sales split, but the data is done by title i.e. Mr, Mrs, Miss & Ms.

I have for men:

```
men = cd.loc[cd.title_desc == "MR", "SALES"]
```

For women I want MR, MRS & MISS included i.e.

```
women = cd.loc[cd.title_desc == "MRS" and "MISS" and "MS", "SALES"]
```

but obviously the "and" isn't correct.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has definitely been asked before, but here you go.

To create two different Series objects by filtering on multiple values:

```
men = cd.loc[cd.title_desc == 'MR','SALES']
women = cd.loc[cd.title_desc.isin(['MRS','MISS','MS']), 'SALES']
```

Alternatively, if you want to go straight to total sales by gender:

```
cd['gender'] = ''
cd.loc[cd.title_desc == 'MR', 'gender'] = 'men'
cd.loc[cd.title_desc.isin(['MRS','MISS','MS']), 'gender'] = 'women'
cd.groupby('gender').agg({'SALES': sum})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to break it up into multiple logical statements, which you can then combine with the logical or operator '|'. The resulting boolean vector can be used with `.loc`

```
bvec = (cd.title_desc == "MRS") | (cd.title_desc == "MISS") | (cd.title_desc == "MS")
women = cd.loc[bvec,"SALES"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do that in Pandas.

One of the best ones IMO the one [@jack6e has shown in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828707/5741205).

Alternatively we can do it in the following ways:

Using RegEx's:

```
cd.loc[cd.title_desc.str.contains(r'^MRS|MISS|MS$'), 'SALES']
```

Using `.query()` method:

```
titles = ['MRS','MISS','MS']
cd.query("title_desc in @titles")['SALES']
```